# correct .ssh/config setup to hop ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, netcat

I have a 2-deep ssh network. I have servers `myserv.co.uk` and server `B`. I have given `myserv.co.uk` an alias via the .ssh/config file, called `A`. server A is password protected, and once inside server A I can `ssh B` without having to use a password.

I used `ssh-keygen` on local machine and copied onto server A so that I can successfully do `ssh A` and not have have to use a password.

All good. However I need to ssh/scp directly into server B. There is a lot of stuff about how to do this, which I have tried to implement. I have the following `.ssh/config`:

```
Host A
        User first.last

        Hostname myserv.co.uk

Host B
        User first.last
        ProxyCommand ssh -W B:22 A
```

so when I do `ssh B` I am asked for a password. This should not happen as once in server A, I can ssh to server B without a password by default. here is the output:

```
$ ssh B

Welcome to myserv

This system is for authorised users, if you do not have authorised access
please disconnect immediately.

Password:
```

I enter the password for server A and this works. I assume this is the case because it is the password for user `first.last`.

Hoever, given that when in server A, I can ssh into server B without a password, and I can ssh from local to server A using keygen, why am I being asked for a password when doing `ssh B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you copy your own public key around to authorized keys on both servers?

You can do it with ssh-copy-id

Comment: this was it. have copied local ssh-key to server B and now works. thank you.